# How to get individual values of a variable while using foreach in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, foreach

I have used a function in jquery that gets all the values from the server side and then on the basis of these values, perform some validations client side. Below is the code that I have used

```
AOT.View.AssetMarkTrustTrust.prototype.validateSubmit = function () {    
var result = false;
var message = '';
result = applicationView.GetCardEmbossings();//this method will get the values from the server side

if (result != null)
    $.each(result, function () {
        if ((result.CardEmbossingLine1.Length > 26) ||
                   (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.CardEmbossingLine2) && result.CardEmbossingLine2.Length > 26) && !result.Suppress) {
            AOT.Utility.displayWarning("Please use Card/Check Editor to specify name that will be printed on card, 26 characters max.");
            return false;
        }
    });

if (!result && !AOT.Utility.isNullEmptyUndefined(message)) {
    AOT.Utility.displayWarning(message, '');
}
return result;
```

};

Problem is that when I check the length of the value CardEmbossingLine1, it shows as undefined. But, there are values under the object result. I cannot fulfil the condition as different values under the object are undefined due to which the condition is not getting fired. Please let me know where am I missing.

Thanks

Comment: put a console.log after the code : result = applicationView.GetCardEmbossings(); and analyze the structure of the object

Comment: `applicationView.GetCardEmbossings();` is this making an ajax call?

Comment: yes, it is making the ajax call

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my variable undefined after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: @Yash: Please read the thread I linked to. It will be clear.

Comment: Try $.each(result, function (index, item) { if ((item.CardEmbossingLine1.Length...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function in "each" can take 2 parameters which is set when jquery iterates thru ur result object.See code below

```
if (result != null)
$.each(result, function (index,eachResult) {
    if ((eachResult.CardEmbossingLine1.Length > 26) ||
               (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eachResult.CardEmbossingLine2) && eachResult.CardEmbossingLine2.Length > 26) && !eachResult.Suppress) {
        AOT.Utility.displayWarning("Please use Card/Check Editor to specify name that will be printed on card, 26 characters max.");
        return false;
    }
});
```